# SSH Port Forwarding -D not working anymore

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

I have a virtual server in the US. When I first set it up I was able to use dynamic port forwarding with

```
ssh -D PORTNUMBER serveraddress
```

After that I could set up Firefox to use that as SOCKS5 proxy. 
I don't know what changed, but for some reason that doesn't work anymore.

Is there a place, where it is set if tunneling is allowed or not? I tried ssh_config file, there was in fact a

```
Tunnel yes/no
```

option, but even after switching it to yes and restarting, it didn't change anything.

Where should I look?

EDIT (01:41 GMT+1):
The output with -vvv options is rather long, therefore uploaded it to pastebin. I hopefully removed all sensitive data:
http://pastebin.com/r4BVC5F1

EDIT (02:13 GMT+1):
New output file: http://pastebin.com/VvPVv0ff

I added the "PermitTunnel" option in my config file, now I can log in with -vvv active. However the proxy still won't work. I havent changed on settings on the client side, at least none that I know of. And yes, I 'm using Mac OSX.

EDIT (09:45 GMT+1):
Could this have anything to do with messed up hostnames? Or maybe dante or squid configurations intereferring? I seriously don't know, why it's not working anymore...

LAST EDIT:
OK, I'm just plainly stupid! Seriously. Everything worked fine. The problem was that I typed in the IP address of my server into the SOCKS server settings. Which can't possibly work. localhost ist of course the right answer. Darn... wasted so much time... Thanks everyone!

Comment: can you post the result when you add the option `-vvv`?

Comment: updated first post.

Comment: Can you connect to other servers?

Comment: I can connect other servers over ssh jsut fine. I mean, I can connect to the server in the US as well. Only port forwarding doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also an option called `PermitTunnel`. Make sure this is set to `yes`. If you can't find it, add it.

In your `-vvv`-log, it says `Exit status 127`, this is set by bash when it can not find the command. This could mean it's a client problem. I think you are using OSX, right?

Can you connect to another server? Maybe localhost? Has anything changed to your ssh-client installation? Nothing in `.ssh/config`?

Comment: I don't see any "PermitTunnel" option. There is only "PermitLocal...".

Answer (score 0):

in sshd_config 
1- change pertmitunnel to yes

from command line sudo service sshd restart.

That should solve the problem.